# powershell convert timegenerated format to US format (mmddyyyy)

Tags: powershell

i'm pulling a log from a remote server in the UK (I'm in the U.S.) and i want to convert the timegenerated field to U.S. format, mmddyyyy hh:ss (month first). Since the server is in the UK, it comes out as ddmmyyyy.

here's the current script i'm using, can someone help me figure this out please?
Thanks!

```
$Date = (get-date)
$Server = "SERVERNAME"
$logName = '{0}{1}_{2}_security_4625_log.csv' -f "c:\Report\",
$Server,$Date.tostring("MMM-dd-yyyy")


Get-EventLog -LogName 'Security' -Computer $Server `
 -InstanceId 4625 `
 -After $Date.adddays(-7) |
 Select-Object @{
  Name='WorkstationName'
  Expression={$_.ReplacementStrings[1] -replace '\$$'}
 },
 Timegenerated,
 @{
  Name='IpAddress'
  Expression={$_.ReplacementStrings[-2]}
 },
 @{
  Name='TargetUserName'
  Expression={$_.ReplacementStrings[5]}
 } |
 Export-Csv -Path $logName -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Hi, I have a French locale (date format is `dd/mm/yyyy`) and `(Get-Date).ToString("MMM-dd-yyyy")` seems to work as you want it to

Comment: do you mean on the first line?
$Date = (get-date).ToString("MMM-dd-yyyy")

Comment: At what line to you get a "reversed" format ?

Comment: Right in the middle where it says Timegenerated. The data that it is pulling from there is in ddmmyy format. i want it in mmddyy format

Comment: nevermind, i got it figured out.

Comment: I really wonder what the issue was, can you please make a formal answer ?